# Put blank in sql server column with integer datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with values like  0, 1, 2, 3 , -1, -2, 9, 8, etc. I want to put "blank" in column where number is less then 0, i.e. it should show all records and whereever the position is less than 0 it should show ''.

I tried using STR but this made my query too slow. The query looks like this:

```
select CASE 
WHEN position < 0 THEN ''
ELSE position
END Position, column2
from
(
    Select STR (column1) as position, column2 from table
) as t1
```

Can anybody suggest a better way to show the '' in column1? is there other way around? what can i use instead of str?

Update: column1 is int type and i do not want to put null but an empty string. I know i can't show empty string in an int column so have to use cast. Just wanted to be sure that it should not slow down my query, looking for the best option which returns the results in less time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the `CASE` expression into the query, and replace `STR` with a `CAST`, like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN position < 0 THEN '' ELSE CAST(column1 as VARCHAR(10)) END as position
,   column2
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
Select 
  case 
  when column1 <0 then null
  else column1 
  end as position, column2 
from tab
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `STR` on all rows and compare strings. Instead compare integers and use `STR` only where needed:

```
SELECT 
 CASE WHEN column1 < 0 THEN ''
      ELSE STR (column1) 
  END AS position
, column2 
FROM table
```

Answer (score 2):

also you can use the following

```
coalesce(convert(varchar(10),position),'')
```

this is just in case of you have null values in int field and you want to show it

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Position < 0
        THEN ''
        ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), Position)
    END AS Position,
    column2
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use blank spaces you'll need to convert the field to a string type.
Try something like this:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN COLUMN1 < 0 THEN '' 
         ELSE POSITION 
       END Position, 
       COLUMN2 
FROM   (SELECT CAST(COLUMN1 AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS position, 
               COLUMN2 
        FROM   TABLE, 
               COLUMN1) AS t1
```

I use both the original column and the converted, since after conversion the `< 0` works differently and we will get unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks Gidil, this shows the result as expected. i would be having thousands of records so do you think it would not slow down my query, as str took around 30 minutes to retreive records so just wondering how much time cast will take. Is using cast better than STR?

Comment: It should be faster. STR is used for conversion from numeric data, not integers, that's at least part of the reason it works slowly. CAST or CONVERT should be much faster.