# In SQL Server, casting varchar to int converts the blank to 0, is there a way to avoid this?

Tags: sql-server, r, casting

```
 sample0 <- paste("SELECT cast([Date] as Date) as Date values (NULL)
              ,[Major_Asset_Class] values (NULL)
              ,[Country] values (NULL)
              ,cast([CPI_Index] as float) as CPI_Index values (NULL)
              ,cast([GDP] as float) as GDP values (NULL)
              ,cast([",Local_Earning_Index,"] as float) as Local_Earning_Index values (NULL)
              ,cast([",Local_MARKET_CAP,"] as float) as Local_MARKET_CAP values (NULL)
              ,cast([",Local_NET_DVD,"] as float) as Local_NET_DVD values (NULL)
              ,cast([",Local_Price_Index,"] as float) as Local_Price_Index values (NULL)
              ,cast([",MSCI_Earning_Index,"] as float) as MSCI_Earning_Index values (NULL)
              ,cast([",MSCI_MARKET_CAP,"] as float) as MSCI_MARKET_CAP values (NULL)
              ,cast([",MSCI_NET_DVD,"] as float) as MSCI_NET_DVD values (NULL)
              ,cast([",MSCI_Price_Index,"] as float) as MSCI_Price_Index values (NULL)
              ,cast([",Volitility_Index,"] as FLOAT) as Volitility_Index values (NULL)
              ,cast([",Local_TtlGrs_Return,"] as float) as Local_TtlGrs_Return values (NULL)
              ,cast([",Local_TtlNet_Return,"] as float) as Local_TtlNet_Return into values (NULL)
              Last_Month_Data_1$ 
              FROM [Tableau].[dbo].[Last_Month_Data]",sep="")
```

I don't want the blanks in each column to convert to 0s. How can i avoid that?

Comment: what do you want to convert them to?

Comment: want the conversion to work as it is except that the blanks should remain blanks

Comment: but a blank isn't an integer, it's a string

Comment: "Blank" doesn't exist in integer. In a string it's "", what do you expect for int?

Comment: Null perchance?

Comment: Because the rest of my data is like that...integer column but a blank for a blank....

Comment: a column has a single data type in SQL Server. You can't have an integer column with a blank space. You might have a string column which happens to have stored only numbers

Comment: what about null?

Comment: then use @steveB's answer, but change `ISNULL` with `NULLIF`

Comment: cool bro thanks for that

Comment: can i do nullif(filename, NULL) ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post,
[Put blank in sql server column with integer datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616167/put-blank-in-sql-server-column-with-integer-datatype)

it shows how to replace the 0's with empty strings

Comment: this isn't converting the values to int, though, is using a string

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your cast in a isnull statement and tell sql server what you want null values to be set too:

```
isnull(filename,<New value>)
```

where  can be 0, -1, or any other valid value, an int since you are casting to int. The final line with casting would be

```
cast(isnull(fieldname,'-1') as int)
```

Assuming you want null's to be -1

If you want a blank, you'll need to use a case statement to determine if it is null, then return as a string, else return the value. See first answers link for example or as follows:

```
case when (isnull(fieldname,'') = '') then ''
     else cast(fieldname as int)
     end as fieldname
```

First line checks if the fields value is null and returns '' as existing type (varchar in your case), else it does the cast to int.

Comment: `ISNULL` doesn't work like that, you are thinking of `NULLIF`

Comment: in ms sql-server, at least in 2000 - 2012, isnull can be used to check if null and return an alternate value for null. I use it all the time. See Microsoft documents: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql  Syntax is: ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )

Comment: But op wants something different, to set a `NULL` value when receiving an empty space, so you should use `NULLIF`: `SELECT CAST(NULLIF(column,'') AS INT)`

Comment: You make a good point. I assumed they wanted something other then 0, your saying they want the cast to return blank or null on the cast. In that case, the case statement linked from the first answer  is a better solution.

Comment: can i do nullif(filename, NULL) ?

Comment: NULLIF(value1, value2) does a compare between the values and if they don't match, returns a null. When you cast to int, the cast will return a 0. I'm going to update the second half of my answer to show using a case statement to return blank. the only issue is that you are now mixing varchars, and ints, depending on your receiving system.